# How to fix this error "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined" where i am going wrong

Tags: reactjs

Can you help me run this react component without error. Bubble sorting function. I am just a beginner.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

export default class NumberSortingRef extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.myFun = this.myFun.bind(this);
    }

    NumberSorting = () => {
        const bSort = (arr) => {
        var length = arr.length;
        for(let i=0; i < length; i++) {
            for(let j=0; j < length - i; j++) {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                let temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
        return arr;
    }

        const arrayToInt = (arr) => {
            let arrayInt = [];
            for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arrayInt[i] = parseInt(arr[i]);
            }
            return arrayInt;
        }

        const myFun = () => {
            var str = document.getElementById("demo").value;
            var arr = str.split(',');
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = bSort(arrayToInt(arr));
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="demo" />
                <Button onClick={this.myFun}>Show</Button>
                <p id="result"></p>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.myfun` is not a property of your component, because it's nested inside other method. Even though `myfun` is a const, his scope belongs to your method `NumberSorting`, not to the component.

Answer (score -1):

#### Solve

just change

`const myFun = () => {`

to

`myFun = () => {`

#### Related

[const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

[class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: @RakeshPonakalla are you sure? remove const not ok?